# Getting 403 forbidden while running flask app on apache(centos 7)

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

I have written a flask rest API which is working fine while executing using the command `sudo python main.py`. I wanted to configure that in apache and below are what I have done.

File structure `/home/user/project_name/src/restApi/`:

```
- __init__.py
- main.py
- app.py
- service.wsgi
```

Here is `main.py`:

```
from app import app

@app.route('/api/v1/fileupload', methods=['POST'])
@auth.login_required
def upload_file():
  // code


@auth.verify_password
def verify(username, password):
    if not (username and password):
        return False
    return USERNAME == username and PASSWORD == password

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Here is my `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
//some config
```

Here is my `service.wsgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

sys.path.insert(3, "/home/user/project_name/src/restApi/")
from app import app as application
```

Here is `/etc/httpd/config/httpd.config`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 34.73.243.234
    DocumentRoot /home/user/project_name/src/restApi/
    WSGIScriptAlias /api/v1/fileupload /home/user/project_name/src/restApi/service.wsgi
    <Directory /home/user/project_name/src/restApi/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Apologies, if I haven't explained very well. Well, when I am running `main.py` using the command `sudo python main.py` that time I am able to upload the file. But after configured apache and hitting the same URL getting a response as 403 forbidden `You don't have permission to access /api/v1/fileupload on this server.`

Please help me out. I've tried all the solutions, couldn't end up to fix the bug.
Thanks

Comment: Did you restart Apache service?

Comment: Yes I have restarted Apache server using `sudo apachectl restart`

Answer (score 0):

In

```
/etc/httpd/config/httpd.config
```

You have standing DocumentRoot, I mean this should be commented